# Как использовать библиотеку в C++?

Tags: c++

Изначально задача была в том, чтобы добавить некоторые классы\функции в проект, но так, чтобы их можно было бы использовать и в другом проекте. Но таскать за собой и .cpp и .h не хочется, поэтому я попробовал написать библиотеку (.lib) в VS2022

[image: библиотека]

Я написал одну функцию в ней, собрал, в итоге есть файл .lib. Но как теперь его добавить в проект и там воспользоваться? Я пробовал через свойства и там указал доп зависимости, доп каталоги библиотек, даже через `pragma comment(lib, "libname.lib")`, но функцией воспользоваться не получилось. Возможно, я вообще не с того начал, так что как собрать в один файл некоторые функции и классы, чтобы его можно было таскать и пихать в проекты?

Comment: *"функцией воспользоваться не получилось"* А ошибку мы должны телепатически угадать, ага.

Comment: .lib файл избавит вас только от таскания .cpp. (.h файлы все равно понадобятся.)

Comment: не получилось просто потому что ее не видно, т. е. я вроде библиотеку получил, но она будто бы не определена. А если .lib избавит только от cpp, то как все в один файл запихнуть, так можно вообще?

Comment: В С++ избавиться от заголовочных файлов невозможно. Заголовочные файлы - краеугольный камень языка.

Comment: тогда зачем вообще нужны библиотеки?

Comment: Статическая библиотека содержит прекомпилированые единицы трансляции. При использовании статических библиотек заголовочные файлы необходимо подключать по-прежнему. По сравнению с некоторыми другими языками такскание зависимостей в С++ - это боль. @Chorkov Для избавления от заголовочных файлов (и от статических библиотек заодно) в С++20 добавили модули https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170